# Проблема в chrome

Tags: google-chrome, веб-программирование, php, изображения, браузер

Доброй ночи, дорогие про.

Хочу получить совет от тех, кто, возможно, сталкивался с такой проблемой. В общем, есть страница. Она выводит 10 картинок на сайт. Имеется постраничная навигация. То есть можно пролистать страницы сайта и просмотреть по 10 штук, допустим, 100 картинок. Если мы заходим на сайт, то все нормально, пролистаем страницы 2-3 - все путем, а вот если потом вернуться на первую страницу, то возникает проблема - пустой лист. Точнее лист не пустой, если просмотреть исходный код страницы, то все данные выведены. Проблема наблюдается только в chrome. IE, opera, safari, mazilla работают со страницей нормально.

Вопрос, чем может быть вызвано подобное поведение chrome? Может ли сказываться на поведении браузера тот факт, что я погружаю на страницу картинки-оригиналы, каждая в разрешении 1920х1080 и весом 400-500 кб.

P.S. Если белый лист обновить, то все картинки и подписи под ними становятся видны.

Comment: Можно пример, чтобы самим глянуть?

Comment: Невыполнимая задача без исходного кода. ;)

Comment: http://tellaboutall.ru/wallpapers/all/1

Comment: мне вот это странным кажется

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://tellaboutall.ru/404.php".`

но глючит, возможно, из-за хака с overflow: hidden у project list, в calculated properties у него ширина не растягивается, возможно, вместо float: left вам подойдет display: inline-block

Comment: Так основная забава в том, что
http://tellaboutall.ru/articles/all/1
Вот тут, допустим, т.е. в разделе статей - такого вообще никогда не бывает. А страница с обойками полностью отсюда копировалась.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем примере помогает такой "хак":

```
#content { -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); }
```

P.S. Все чаще и чаще появляются такого рода глюки, что приходится переносить некий контент на аппаратный слой, если быть честным, сам до конца не понял, почему так бывает.

Comment: Спасибо за инфо. Посмотрим, что из этого всего выйдет.

Answer (score 1):

Проверено эмпирически: убрать `overflow: hidden;` у элемента `#content` и страница отобразится.
Странно вот что - когда страницы отображаются, то этого элемента вообще нету, а когда ничего не отображается (что логично - у него же скрытое свойство), то этот контейнер содержит весь код и скрывает его.
Что-то где-то неверно генерирует вьюху - поправьте вёрстку и пойдёт дело.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, посмотрим, что выйдет. Но я уже приводил в комментариях ссылку на раздел сайта, который функционирует нормально, хотя структура страницы полностью с него копировалась.